# Ubuntu Android emulator: error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> connection refused

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, ubuntu-14.04

I have created an virtual android device using android-sdk-linux in Ubuntu-14.04. When I try to start it, It is not work. I started it in debug mode then it gives me an error "error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> connection refused". Please help.